# If a row has a particular entry, creating a blank line in the output

Tags: awk

I have input.txt like so:

```
237 @
0 2 3 4 0. ABC
ABC
DEF
@ 237
0 1 4 7 2 0.
0 3 8 9 1 0. GHI
XYZ
```

(a) If a row contains the symbol `@`, then, in the output, I want a newline/blankline.

(b) If a row starts with a `0` and contains `0.` then, the interval of such entries excepting the terminating `0.` should be displayed.

The following script accomplishes (b)

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
        if($i == "0")
            {arr[NR] = $i}
        else
            if ($i == "0.") 
                {break}
            else 
                {arr[NR]=arr[NR]" "$(i)}}
    ($1 == "0") {print arr[NR]}
    ' input.txt > output.txt
```

so that the output is:

```
0 2 3 4
0 1 4 7 2
0 3 8 9 1
```

How can (a) be accomplished so that the output is:

```
                // <----Starting newline
0 2 3 4

0 1 4 7 2
0 3 8 9 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try add `if ($0 ~ /@/) {print ""}`

so

```
awk '{
    for (i=1; i<NF; i++)
        if($i == "0")
            {arr[NR] = $i}
        else
            if ($i == "0.") 
                {break}
            else 
                {arr[NR]=arr[NR]" "$(i)}
    if ($0 ~ /@/) {print ""} 
    ($1 == "0") {print arr[NR]}
    ' soinput.txt > output.txt
```

Comment: This worked without the starting if: i.e.,  `($0 ~ /@/) {print ""} `

Comment: That would fail if a row contained `0` in the middle as it'd truncate the row to start at that point, e.g. try it with input like `0 1 2 0 3 4 0.`. There's also no point looping over all the fields populating a variable for every line and then discarding it if the line didn't start with `0` vs only populating it if the line started with `0`, and there's no need to store all of the input in an array indexed by line number, a scalar variable would do without wasting all that memory.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're trying to do?

```
$ awk '/@/{print ""} /^0/ && sub(/ 0\..*/,"")' file

0 2 3 4

0 1 4 7 2
0 3 8 9 1
```

Comment: TY! The other poster was possibly responding to my OP where I had set this up. As you point out in your comment, it does waste memory storing unnecessary rows. However, that is easier for me to understand. While your answer is succint, I have a tough time understanding what is going on --- due to my ignorance on details of awk.

Comment: Well, what do you THINK is going on? There's nothing in my script any more complicated than in your existing script, less so IMHO, so I expect if you thought about it and took a guess at what it's doing you'd get it right. Feel free to ask if you have a specific question abut any part of it though.